# set entire row to value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `atype`

```
    AT  N   term
1   4   1   1
2   3   2   1
3   2   3   2
4   1   4   2
```

i need to set the entire row of a new `dataframe` to term value from `atype`. Is this the best way to accomplish the task?

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = atype.index, columns=atype.index)
m2 = pd.DataFrame(0, index = atype.index, columns=atype.index)


for i in range(1, atype.shape[0]+1):
    m1.ix[i] = atype.ix[i,"term"]
    m2[i] = atype.ix[i,"term"]
```

or is there a better/ more efficient way in where i dont need to use a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [91]: pd.DataFrame([atype.term.values.tolist()] * len(atype),
                      columns=atype.index, index=atype.index).T
Out[91]:
   1  2  3  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  1
3  2  2  2  2
4  2  2  2  2

In [92]: pd.DataFrame([atype.term.values.tolist()] * len(atype),
                      columns=atype.index, index=atype.index)
Out[92]:
   1  2  3  4
1  1  1  2  2
2  1  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2
4  1  1  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this is what i needed. Just a faster more efficient approach

Comment: @user7331243, glad i could help :)